# REST client that can handle login via oauth

Tags: testing, rest, oauth, restful-authentication, black-box

I am working as a tester on a system based on a Rest API. Part of my job is to use different applications to POST files to the Rest API and then accessing the API directly via a Rest Client to verify that the XML is correct.

So far I have been using the RESTClient firefox add-on.

But now we are getting rid of our old login in favour of Oauth. This all good and all but it makes testing harder since I can't ( don't know how? ) how to access the Rest API using the REST client I am using. And I don't know of any other REST client that can do this.

I need a REST Client/REST browser that can handle login via oauth.

**Update:**
Hi. I am still looking for more good REST Clients that can handle Oauth. So if you know any I would appreciate a post below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out RESTClient does support oauth but that the new version has not been released yet.

Checkout the lastest codes from sourceforge 
http://sourceforge.net/projects/restclient/develop
And use those files to replace your RESTClient (which should be found in your firefox profile directory
http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/Profiles#How_to_find_your_profile ).

**Note:** I had to hack the source and remove the "realm" parameters since our system didn't want it. According to Oauth spec realm is optional and I have asked the developers of RESTClient to make it optional in the future releases.

Answer (score 6):

I was also looking for such a thing and since this question things seem to have moved on a bit.

I'm using Chrome and the REST Console extension works brilliantly for me:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cokgbflfommojglbmbpenpphppikmonn

Comment: I would recommend Chrome POSTMAN over RESTClient since it has few bugs((https://github.com/chao/RESTClient/issues/105)) that lead to invalid signature.

Answer (score 3):

I'm author of RESTClient, and I already started to develop a new version of RESTClient (version 1.4.0). The new version will support oAuth 2.0. And it will be released in April.

Comment: Are you talking about the Firefox Plugin? I have noticed that a lot of Rest Clients are called RESTClient. For example WizzTools have a software also called RESTClient http://code.google.com/p/rest-client/

Comment: Yes, I just submitted a new version of RESTClient to Mozilla, but I still haven't finished oAuth 2.0 yet. I hope I will finish it in this month.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing that prohibits you from continuing to test a REST API manually when it uses OAuth authentication.  OAuth simply requires that you send additional parameters: first that you negotiate the OAuth dance to get a request token and exchange it for an access token and then that each request has the necessary [OAuth parameters](http://oauth.net/core/1.0a/#anchor12) (`oauth_consumer_key`, `oauth_token`, `oauth_signature_method`, `oauth_signature`, `oauth_timestamp` and `oauth_nonce`).  You'd need to use a separate tool to do the signing (unless the product you're testing is willing to use `PLAINTEXT` as the signature method), but you could simply copy all of these values in manually to your current manual tool.

If that sounds like a lot of work, you're right!  I think this is a good time to switch to automated testing.  [Libraries exist](http://oauth.net/code/) for most languages to consume OAuth services programmatically and that would handle all of those parameters and signing for you.  You could build a generic tool that let a manual tester specify URLs and parameters by hand, or go farther and write something that did all the generation and validation automatically.

**Update**: for doing some exploratory testing from the command line, it would certainly be helpful to have a `curl`-like tool that handles some of the OAuth paramaters and signing.  Check out [oauth-proxy](http://mojodna.net/2009/08/21/exploring-oauth-protected-apis.html) which may work for you -- it's intended exactly for exploring APIs on the command line.  Or you may find that for your particular explorations, you want to build a script around oauth-proxy or a tool on top of one of the many OAuth libraries for different languages.

Comment: Thanks for your good answer. I was afraid that it would be a drag using our current tool and you confirmed it. We already do automated testing but we also need to do manual exploratory testing using REST Client. 
I can't belive there is not a open source tool for this.

Comment: Yeah, that's a good point, @Jonas.  Sometimes you need to do manual exploratory testing of an API.  I've added a link to oauth-proxy to the answer which might work for you, and I'd be very interested to know of other such convenience tools.

Comment: Thanks for all your help. I managed to find a tool that can do what I need. See my answer below.